# QMenu и кнопки управления окном

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyside2

При нажатии на кнопки меню (отмечены на картинке), кнопки управления окном (свернуть, развернуть, закрыть) не срабатывают с первого клика, только со второго (с первого "убирается фокус" с кнопок меню). Так и задумано?  Можно как-то это исправить?

Обычные кнопки (внутри окна) нажимаются с первого клика, как и должно быть, т.ч. если ставить флаг `FramelessWindowHint` и рисовать свои кнопки управления, то не должно мешать.

[image: меню]

Вот код для воспроизведения:

**main.py**

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

from menu_1 import *

class Main_window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent);

        self.setupUi(self);

        # self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.box.setStyleSheet("#box{border: 1px solid #f00}");

        self.btn = QPushButton("btn", self.box);
        self.btn.setGeometry(10, 10, 100, 20);

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.create);


        self.menu = QMenu(self);
        self.act0 = QAction("0", self);
        self.act1 = QAction("1", self);
        self.menu.addAction(self.act0);
        self.menu.addAction(self.act1);


        self.btn_minimize = QPushButton("min win", self.box);
        self.btn_minimize.setGeometry(490, 10, 100, 20);

        self.btn_minimize.clicked.connect(self.showMinimized);



    def create(self, e):
        print("Create", self.btn.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)), self.btn.pos(), self.btn.rect(), self.btn.geometry())

        pos = self.btn.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, 0)) + QPoint(0, self.btn.height())
        self.menu.popup(pos);




def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv);
    window = Main_window();
    window.show();
    sys.exit(app.exec_());


if ( __name__ == "__main__" ):
    main();
```

**menu_1.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'menu_1.ui',
# licensing of 'menu_1.ui' applies.
#
# Created: Sat Mar  9 11:06:35 2019
#      by: pyside2-uic  running on PySide2 5.12.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.box = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.box.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 600, 400))
        self.box.setObjectName("box")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menumenu_0 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menumenu_0.setObjectName("menumenu_0")
        self.menusub_0 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menumenu_0)
        self.menusub_0.setObjectName("menusub_0")
        self.menusub_00 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menusub_0)
        self.menusub_00.setObjectName("menusub_00")
        self.menusub_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menumenu_0)
        self.menusub_1.setObjectName("menusub_1")
        self.menumenu_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menumenu_1.setObjectName("menumenu_1")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionsub_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_2.setObjectName("actionsub_2")
        self.actionsub_000 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_000.setObjectName("actionsub_000")
        self.actionsub_001 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_001.setObjectName("actionsub_001")
        self.actionsub_002 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_002.setObjectName("actionsub_002")
        self.actionsub_01 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_01.setObjectName("actionsub_01")
        self.actionsub_02 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_02.setObjectName("actionsub_02")
        self.actionsub_10 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_10.setObjectName("actionsub_10")
        self.actionsub_11 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionsub_11.setObjectName("actionsub_11")
        self.menusub_00.addAction(self.actionsub_000)
        self.menusub_00.addAction(self.actionsub_001)
        self.menusub_00.addAction(self.actionsub_002)
        self.menusub_0.addAction(self.menusub_00.menuAction())
        self.menusub_0.addAction(self.actionsub_01)
        self.menusub_0.addAction(self.actionsub_02)
        self.menusub_1.addAction(self.actionsub_10)
        self.menusub_1.addAction(self.actionsub_11)
        self.menumenu_0.addAction(self.menusub_0.menuAction())
        self.menumenu_0.addAction(self.menusub_1.menuAction())
        self.menumenu_0.addAction(self.actionsub_2)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menumenu_0.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menumenu_1.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, -1))
        self.menumenu_0.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "menu_0", None, -1))
        self.menusub_0.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_0", None, -1))
        self.menusub_00.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_00", None, -1))
        self.menusub_1.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_1", None, -1))
        self.menumenu_1.setTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "menu_1", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_2.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_2", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_000.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_000", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_001.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_001", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_002.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_002", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_01.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_01", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_02.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_02", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_10.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_10", None, -1))
        self.actionsub_11.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "sub_11", None, -1))
```

**UPD**
Проверил на другой машине (win 10) - проблема повторяется, это как-нибудь лечится?

Comment: В PyQt5 все кнопки срабатывают с первого клика.

Comment: @S.Nick Заменил в импортах PySide2 на PyQt5, ничего не поменялось.  Значит это в моей системе проблема, получается.  Win7x64, Python 3.6.8, если вдруг.

Comment: я проверял в Windows 10, Python 3.5.2, PyQt 5.11.2